# pm2 i want to store my logs (example. error.log ) in a custom folder

Tags: node.js, pm2

I want to save all log file and store in a custom folder to download Please help me. I  already try lots of time through eocsystem.json by path changing but do not get any file in the selected path.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify custom logs path, format of logs, date/time format using pm2 config file

Example :

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "Demo",
            "script": "./index.js",         
            "log": "./pm2-log/out-err.log",
            "log_type": "json",
            "log_date_format": "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm"
        }
    ]
}
```

this will create new folder pm2-log in current directory and store all logs in out-err.log file.

You can also separate logs by giving different path for error/output

```
        "output": "./out.log",
        "error": "./error.log",
```

For more detail, you may check this  https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/guide/log-management/

Answer (score 1):

From the pm2 documentation, you can specify the log path for pm2 with the argument `-o <path>` for main log and `-e <path>` for error log, or `-l <path>` for both.

```
$ mkdir log/
$ pm2 start server.js -o log/pm2.log -e log/error.log
```

Comment: Thank you for your response ; but is it possible by set of ecosystem.json file that store every days log ?. I want to download the log file  by button click from admin interface..

Comment: Maybe try to add `out_file: log/pm2.log, error_file: log/error.log` in your ecosystem.json config file.